# Laravel MySQL Query Order By ID Desc Is Slow

Tags: mysql, laravel, query-optimization

I have a table `prospects` that has 6 million rows.

I have such a code snippet, the performance of it is killing me.

```
 $prospects = Prospect::where('channel_id', 1)
            ->orderBy('id', 'desc')
            ->offset(0)
            ->limit(100)
            ->get();
```

> select   `id` from   `prospects` where   `channel_id` = 1 order by
> `id` desc limit   100 offset 0

It takes **17.0426 seconds.**

```
    $prospects = Prospect::where('channel_id', 1)
        ->orderBy('id', 'asc')
        ->offset(0)
        ->limit(100)
        ->get();
```

> select   `id` from   `prospects` where   `prospects`.`deleted_at` is
> null order by   `id` desc limit   100 offset 0

Such version takes **0.0262 seconds** (ascending order)

How can I improve the performance when the order is DESC? `id` is a PK, `channel_id` I have an index on it. I also have created a DESC index on `id` (I read somewhere that two indexes: one ASC and one desc might help), but It did not.

I also noticed that if there is no WHERE in sql like this:

```
    $prospects = Prospect::orderBy('id', 'desc')
        ->offset(0)
        ->limit(100)
        ->get();
```

> select   * from   `prospects` where   `prospects`.`deleted_at` is null
> order by   `id` desc limit   100 offset 0

Then it takes **0.0284 seconds**

`channel_id` is an FK to the `channels` table. I have two records there with ids 1 and 2. I noticed that such

```
    $prospects = Prospect::where('channel_id', 2)->orderBy('id', 'desc')
        ->offset(0)
        ->limit(100)
        ->get();
```

query (where channel_id is 2) takes **0.0262 seconds.**

I have 5.2 million prospects that have channel_id 2 and 1.7 million prospects where channel_id is 1. So somehow query with channel_id = 2 is 100 times faster than channel_id = 1. How can that be? Can the size of the row data affect this? (Cause prospects with channel_id = 1 has a `data` column which contains more data than prospects with channel_id = 2)

Comment: have you tried using composite index on both `channel_id` and `id`

Comment: and how many records you have?

Comment: Hi, I updated the question. I have ~7million records.

Comment: To help you with your [tag:query-optimization] question, we need more information. Please [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/query-optimization/info), then [edit] your question.

Answer (score 0):

```
INDEX(channel_id,    -- because of WHERE channel_id = constant
      id)            -- because of ORDER BY id
```

In *this* query, the index can be used both for the `WHERE` and the `ORDER BY`.  However, if you have, say `OFFSET 234000`, it will have to scan 234000+100 rows to get the result; that is `OFFSET` can be a performance killer when it is large.

Do you really expect a user to page through 1.7M rows??